# How to make my object live even my app closed

Tags: android, object, callback, object-lifetime

I got a situation where i have two APPS for simplicity keep it as `APP1` and `APP2`, i am passing an object `remoteCallback` as `CALLBACK` from APP1 to APP2 for future use.

where based on result APP2 will instantiate a method `updateStatus(String msg)` using a object `remoteCallback`, Everything is working fine but, when i close the APP1 and clears the memory, APP2 is unable to call the method i know what causes this problem i want to know is there any way to make the object(remoteCallback) live even the APP1 closed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  is no way we cant stop an app from destroy so instead of passing an callback to get details use `BROADCAST RECEIVER`.
This is the solution i adapted to this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an unbound `Service` here. Unbound services make that even if one of your apps close, if the conditions permit it, it will still be running in the background. If you used a bound `Service`, it would stop with your app if your app stopped.

This differs from an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`, because even if they run in the background, there's a big change of being killed if Android needs more memory or is in lack of resources.

This introduce, however, a new responsibility for you: You'll have to make sure you use `startService()` or `stopService()` accordingly within your app and don't leave your `Service` running indefinitely.

[This](http://navinsandroidtutorial.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/android-services-unbound-and-bound.html) seems to be a good example about how it works, but you might find lots of documentation about unbound `Service`s

Comment: I tried the unbound service but its not working.that means whenever i force closed the app that object is lost.But any ways that is good answer +1.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention: If you want it to be a `Service` that doesn't close after app closing, declare it as a **foreground** service. This will prevent stopping the declared `Service` much better if you declare it as a background `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

**"I want to know is there any way to make the object(remoteCallback) live even the APP1 closed."**

PendingIntent ?...

Its the same mechanism used on notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the background service and the store the object which you want to live object after the app is closing

you can declare the public static data member and you use the whole application